# Non type-variable argument in the constraint error, while using with infix

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

Unfortunately I have been facing a strange error. It happens while using infix with data constructor.

I am new to Haskell. Can any one help me in this regard ?

```
Prelude> data L a = Cons a (L a) | Emp deriving Show
Prelude> 10 `Cons` Emp
Cons 10 Emp
Prelude> 10 `Cons` 10 `Cons` Emp

<interactive>:43:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (L a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (L a)) => L (L a)
Prelude> 10 `Cons` (10 `Cons` Emp) 
Cons 10 (Cons 10 Emp)
Prelude> 10 `Cons` 10 `Cons` Emp

<interactive>:45:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (L a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (L a)) => L (L a)
Prelude> data L a = Emp | Cons a (L a)  deriving Show
Prelude> 10 `Cons` 10 `Cons` Emp

<interactive>:47:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (L a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num (L a)) => L (L a)
Prelude>
```

Comment: As you've found out, the issue is about the associativity. Even though it is not an exact duplicate, the answer here perfectly explains the behaviour and how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139066/haskell-infix-function-application-precedence

Comment: `Cons` needs to be a right-associative operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the data constructor to be right-associative,

```
infixr 5 `Cons`

data L a = Cons a (L a) | Emp deriving Show
```

Then it will work as you expected.

```
main = print $ (21::Int) `Cons` 42 `Cons` Emp

-- => Cons 21 (Cons 42 Emp)
```

Comment: Can I avoid `5` in infixr 5 ` Cons  like infixr  `Cons?

Comment: you need to give it _some_ preference.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is to write the following `Cons 10 (Cons 10 Emp)` with infix operators.

When you make an ordinary function infix using backticks, (`), the infix operator is left associative. This means that:

```hs
λ> 10 `Cons` 10 `Cons` Emp
```

will be parenthesized as follows:

```
λ> ((10 `Cons` 10) `Cons` Emp)
```

While you want it to be:

```
λ> 10 `Cons` ( 10 `Cons` Emp)
```

Because that's equal `Cons 10 (Cons 10 Emp)`.

This is of course right associative, therefore you need to explicitly parenthesize it.

Markus Mayr linked the [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139066/haskell-infix-function-application-precedence) that refers to the Haskell Report.